# Would a Raspberry Pi be strong enough to work as a web filter?

Tags: networking

I'm planning to use a Raspberry Pi as a web filter and a proxy for my home network. There are four devices in the network. Will it have enough performance?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on type of filtering/proxying you are trying to implement and load these four devices are generating. It's not about RPI performance, it does have some power under the hood, it's more about how intensive the load will be. Most of proxy/filtering hardware for home use (retail hubs/routers) will have less horse power than the RPI itself, so that in theory should not be a problem.

Comment: You can use FreeBSD and packages similar to pfSense.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [GateSentry for Web filtering on the Pi](http://www.abdullahirfan.com/my-projects/gatesentry/)? It's a simple flash-image-and-start-using solution to Raspberry Pi http/https filtering with a nice admin panel.

My Model B Pi (256Mb), running GateSentry, can easily handle 3-4 devices on my home network.

Answer (score 1):

[Pi-hole](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole) is a nice DNS server for blocking advertisements using your Raspberry Pi. You can even port forward the application to use it in places outside of your home network.